# Remote desktop - Display element in desktop and not transmit via buffer

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtgui, qpixmap

I'm developing a remote desktop for studies and need to display an element on the server screen and not stream to the viewer.

It would be like blocking the client screen and the viewer continues to operate the computer in the background and performing maintenance.

At the moment I'm going to apply the project to my client for maintenance.
The application already works perfectly, only this feature is missing.

Below is the code responsible for transmitting the desktop to the viewer:

```
def _makeFramebuffer(self, width, height):
    pix = QPixmap.grabWindow(QCoreApplication.instance().desktop().winId())
    pix = pix.scaled(width, height)
    if width >= self._maxWidth or height >= self._maxHeight:
        width = self._maxWidth
        height = self._maxHeight
    pix.save(self._buffer, 'jpeg')
    pixData = self._buffer.data()
    self._array.clear()
    self._buffer.close()
    return "%s" % pixData
```

I do not want anything ready, just an insight and a direction. I've been studying and researching for days and I can not find anything.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @eyllanesc How do I lock the server screen and continue to operate through the viewer?

Comment: @eyllanesc similar to teamviewer, I just need to lock the server screen and continue to operate remotely

Comment: @eyllanesc Do you have the availability to make a freelance for me?